# How/Where did the Yautjas (Predators) get the Xenomorphs?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, predator-series, alien-vs.-predator, alien-covenant

The **Yautjas** (or more commonly known simply as **Predators**) are an extra-terrestrial race of warriors who hunt for sport and honor. Their hunts included humans and several species (judging from the trophy room in the picture below) and most prominently the [Xenomorphs XX121](https://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Xenomorph) (or simply Xenomorphs).

[image: wall of tophies with several Xenomorph skeletons]

In the movie ***Prometheus (2012)*** and ***Alien Covenant (2017)***, we see that the **Engineers** developed the crude version of Xenomorphs (to apparently send them to Earth and destroy all life on it) which was finally perfected by David (as per the movie *Alien: Covenant* as mentioned by the answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159889/who-created-the-alien-xenomorph)).

So the question is, how did the Predators get the Xenomorphs? Did they steal the technology from the Engineers? Or were they advanced enough to create an actual species for hunting purposes and it coincidently is the exact same as the one created by the Engineers?

Comment: I think it's sweet that you're trying to puzzle this utter mess out. And more sweet that you think there's an actual canonical answer to this question that isn't going to be a total retcon.

Comment: @Valorum well, I have to try :p

Comment: The Yautjas exist in a paralell world where the utter clusterf**k that is Prometheus never happened. There are no Engineers and the alien is either developed by them for sport or (more likely) found somewhere and then used.
It's all in all a better world, I wish I could live in it as well... but here we are Prometheus happened, someone let Damon Lindelof piss all over it and I had the bad luck of watching it.

Comment: Xenomorphs "**Я**" Us.

Comment: lol Xenomorphs "R" us    funny!!.  can't do the backward R though... :)

Comment: Maybe the Engineers evolved into the Predators?

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is no canonical answer to this and it is unlikely the films will provide one. The main reason for this is that **the *AvP* universe is not part of the Ridley Scott *Alien* franchise** as defined by him.

*Alien vs Predator* started out as a comic book franchise and was one of a series of comic themes that ran at the time with cross overs with various titles. There are also *Alien vs* Batman, Superman and *Predator vs* Batman and Superman comics.

Later the *AvP* stories became novels and from this eventually the *AvP* films where created.

The canon right through this for the creation of the alien creature in no way matched what Scott has now written. Aliens were in the universe but no-one knew where they came from. Predators hunted them seeing them as the ultimate prey.

Now while there is no canon here it is possible to consider 2 ideas,neither of which have anything to back them up.

1. Predators came across the Aliens later on, this makes the historical aspect of *AvP* obsolete and means these films are now non-canon.
2. The Alien created by David is not as unique as he thinks and the genetic soup the Engineers created will inevitably create this creature. This then means that Xenomorphs exist through the universe but humans just don’t know it yet and David isn’t as clever as he thinks he is.
3. We treat the *AvP* storyline as we do the old Expanded universe for *Star Wars*; an alternate timeline where *Prometheus* and *Covenant* never happened.

**I vote for #3.**

Comment: Cannon = Big metal shooty thing. Canon = A body of literary works

Comment: Stupid phone auto correct lol corrected :)

Comment: I think you forgot the video games! </all caps>

Comment: @Valorum I'd hope that a [canon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/canon) (following definition 3) would at least imply some sort of authority. But sadly...

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm. I came here looking for a reason for the exact answer.
I can't make sense of it.... but
We know from 'Prey' the predators have contact with human civilization since,  the 17th century. Given the Yautja in the Predator movies had: kidnaping humans for sport on their world, earlier contact in AvP when humans saw them as gods sacrificing themselves to create the xenomorph to hunt, then being over whelmed and nuking the proximity of their hunting grounds... Which would contradict David in 'Prometheus' as being the robot that created the xenomorphs, eleven years later in Alien: Covenant.
I found this timeline article online: https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a844657/alien-timeline-chronology-prometheus/

I think maybe, the simplest answer is.
A Yautja stole a sample of the Internecivus raptus before the events of Prometheus but have been testing their skills in secret.
And they've been using it as a test of skill since. Getting rid of any evidence. In The Predator we see more about the Yautja how they've grown more advance. While also knowing the M.C. was going to be sent away for having contact. Gives us a picture that the government doesn't want it known about alien life forms. The private companies of the francizes universe seem to know more.
https://www.avclub.com/predator-prey-franchise-timeline-predators-alien-vs-1849345710
Maybe the next film will piece it all together for us with a mega xenomorph from both the Predator, and Alien gene to give us all a shocking conclusion.

Comment: Evidence highlighted in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/237007/122024) suggests that _AvP_ isn't canon to _Prometheus_ and _Covenant_. As such, if you're attempting to tie those things together as a fan, you're basically indulging in a form of fan-faction. Maybe one day the writer/director of a future film in this franchise will attempt to tie all that stuff together, but I wouldn't bet on it. The trend in recent years is for new sequels to ignore most previous sequels and pick up where the early instalments left off.